# List WordPress categories and subcategories with posts

Tags: php, wordpress

Hey wonderful programmer peoples!

I have a fully functioning PHP snippet which lists categories and their posts, but we now have subcategories!
I'd like to extend the current script but at a loss where to start, my PHP knowledge is quite basic but I'm learning..

The function of the script below is to:

1. List categories.
2. List link to post within the category

   ```
   <div class="menu-main-menu-container">
   <ul id="primary-menu" class="menu nav-menu" aria-expanded="false">
       <?php
       $cat_args = array(
           'taxonomy' => 'products-category',
       );
       $categories = get_categories($cat_args);

       foreach ($categories as $category) {
           $cat_query = null;
           $args = array(
               'order' => 'ASC',
               'orderby' => 'title',
               'posts_per_page' => -1,
               'post_type' => 'products',
               'taxonomy' => 'products-category',
               'term' => $category->slug
           );

           $cat_query = new WP_Query($args);
           ?>
           <?php
           if ($cat_query->have_posts()) {
               echo "<li class='page_item'>" . $category->name;
               echo "<ul class='custom-submenu'>";
               while ($cat_query->have_posts()) {
                   $cat_query->the_post();
                   ?>
                   <li>
                       <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                   </li>
                   <?php
               }
               echo "</ul></li>";
           }
           wp_reset_postdata();
       }
       ?>        
   </ul>
   </div>
   ```

What I'd like to achieve is:

1. List categories.
2. If category has subcategory, list subcategories.
3. List link to post within the category/subcategory.

FYI: The above is used as a menu, it currently prints as shown below:
[image]

For example, I'd like to change the first menu item 'Bars' to include 'front bars' and 'back bars' (both subcategories) and then list their posts in further submenus.

Thank you in advance for your assistance and knowledge, I hope I have provided enough information! :)

Comment: Is `Bar` is the parent category and `front bars` and `back bars` are subcategory?
if yes means, where you want to show the post which belongs to the category `Bars`

Comment: Good question! Yes, 'bars' is the parent for 'front bars' and 'back bars'. The parent category will have no posts if it has subcategories, all posts will then be in the subcategories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spent some time with a friend creating this properly, for anyone in search of this in future please see here:

https://freshlondon.biz/wordpress-menu-from-categories-subcategories-and-posts/

**Here's some previews on desktop and mobile:** 
[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I have tried my best.

On here I just make a menu based on the category.
If the category has no subcategory means, I just listed its own post details under submenu and if it has subcategory means just listed the subcategory as a submenu and then listed the subcategories post under that subcategory.

I hope this will help you and which meets your requirement.

```
$category = get_categories();

foreach ($category as $value){
    $cat_id = $value->term_id;
    // Check if this category has a child category
    if(!empty(category_has_children($cat_id))){
        $subcategories = category_has_children($cat_id);?>
    <ul class="parent_menu">
    <?php echo $value->cat_name;
        foreach($subcategories as $subcategory_data) {
            ?>
            <li class="sub_menu">
            <?php echo $subcategory_data->name;
                // function to list all the post details
                get_category_data_post($subcategory_data->term_id);
            ?>
            </li><?php
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
    <?php
    } else{
        // Category which don't have sub category
        if($value->parent ==0) {
            ?>
            <ul class="parent_menu">
                <?php echo $value->cat_name;
                    get_category_data_post($value->term_id);
                ?>
            </ul>
            <?php
        }
    }?>
<?php
}

function category_has_children( $term_id = 0, $taxonomy = 'category' ) {
    $children = get_categories( array(
        'child_of'      => $term_id,
        'taxonomy'      => $taxonomy,
        'hide_empty'    => false
    ) );
    return ( $children );
}

function get_category_data_post($cat_id){
    $args = array(
        'category' => $cat_id
    );
    $posts = get_posts($args);
    foreach ($posts as $val) {
        ?>
        <ol class="sub_menu_2">
            <a href="<?php echo get_post_permalink($val->ID); ?>"></a><?php echo $val->post_title; ?>
        </ol>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: This is amazing, thank you for your time! Could you shed some light on how to make this work for the custom post type as in my example? THANK YOU! <3

Comment: Hey Ramya, I tried changing the top part to include the custom post type as with my example but I cannot get this to work - it does print out the top level category names but nothing further. My PHP is quite weak, I've tried to sort this for hours with your code and I cannot get any further! Any ideas? Thanks in advance for helping! <3

Comment: You want to get only custom post type data for both parent category and subcategory? and one more thing you mean parent category as a top level category. Can you please explain it clearly.

Comment: (Paste from the original post) What I'd like to achieve is: > List categories. > If category has subcategory, list subcategories. > List links to posts within the category/subcategory.